# How to aggregate a groupby function so that the value selected within the group is determined by a corresponding value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate

EDITED: I apologise my question when originally posted missed out key details. Dropping `NaN` rows is not an option because not all groups have a match quality and there is still pricing data that needs to be extracted from the groups.

I have a data frame that looks like the following:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Part Description':['Clutch Set', 'Clutch Set', 'Clutch Set', 'Clutch Set', 'Cambelt Kit', 'Cambelt Kit', 'Cambelt Kit', 'Cambelt Kit', 'Front Bumper', 'Front Bumper'], 'Price':[100, np.nan, np.nan, 50, 1000, np.nan, 500, np.nan, 250, np.nan], 'Match Quality':['Poor', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'Perfect', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})
```

[image]

I wish to group by part description and aggregate price, so that I select the price value where the match quality is not blank. Furthermore, if there are only `NaN` values in the group then the highest price is selected. The desired result from the above data frame would look like so:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Part Description':['Clutch Set', 'Cambelt Kit'], 'Price':[100, 500], 'Match Quality':['Poor', 'Perfect']})
```

[image]

I have been trying to use a method which utilises the aggregate method along with a lambda function:

```
df.groupby(['Part Description']).agg(lambda x: ... )
```

Is there a way I can reference a given price values corresponding match quality within the aggregate lambda function?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it is better to `apply` instead of `agg` becase there is interdependency between columns.

```
df.groupby('Part Description', as_index=False).apply(lambda d: d.dropna())
```

---

```
                   Price Match Quality
Part Description                      
Cambelt Kit        500.0       Perfect
Clutch Set         100.0          Poor
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first dropna by 'Match Quality' and then group:

```
df.dropna(subset=['Match Quality']).groupby(
    'Part Description', as_index=False).agg({
    'Price':'sum', 'Match Quality':'first'})
```